# How to cut out a specific substring?

Tags: regex, perl

I wonder if it is possible to cut a substring from a string if this substring's occurency can be zero or more times using a perl regex?

So for example:

`"foo bar //baz"` and `"foo bar"` should both result into `"foo bar"`, cutting out everything behind a double slash, if it's there.

I know this could be easily achieved using other methods, but I'm interested if a regex oneliner is possible for that.

I tried `($new_string) = ($string =~ /(.*?)(\/\/)*.*/)`
But that does not work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
      _____________ Matches 0 chars at position 0 ("").
     /       ______ Matches 0 chars at position 0 ("").
    /       / _____ Matches 13 chars at position 0 ("foo bar //baz").
  _/  _____/ /
 / \ /     \/\
(.*?)(\/\/)*.*
```

What you want:

```
( my $new_string = $string ) =~ s{//.*}{};

my $new_string = $string =~ s{//.*}{}r;            # 5.14+
```